# fileReader.onload does not run second time, even after selecting different file

Tags: javascript, json, excel, user-interface

```
document.getElementById("uploadExcel").addEventListener("click", function () {
        $("#uploadExcel").attr('disabled', true);
        $('#loader').show();
        if (selectedFile) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            alert("2");
            fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                alert(event);
                var data = event.target.result;
                alert("3");
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                    type: "binary", cellDates: true, dateNF: 'mm/dd/yyyy;@'
                });
                alert("4");
                workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
                    alert("5");
                    let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(
                        workbook.Sheets[sheet]
                    );
                    let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(rowObject);
                    alert("Get Data");
                    getData(jsonObject);
                    //document.getElementById("jsonData").innerHTML = jsonObject;
                });
            };
            alert("6");
            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Now let me explain what is happening:

The page loads and I select the file to upload, it goes through even if it has excel errors, it will take the file and read it, convert it and throw errors.

So then I change that excel file to be error-free and try to click the upload button again, but this time the code enters the above function, and it won't go past `fileReader.onload = function (event)` it alerts "2" and then stops working.

Can you please tell me why is this happening and how to avoid this without a page reload, because if I do a page reload everything works as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Did you reselect the file or is it the original reference?

Comment: I tried to reselect the file, and also tried to keep the original reference, in both the cases it gives the same issue.